# ReentrantLock tryLock(timeout,timeUnit) doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, locking, java.util.concurrent

I have some confuse about ReentrantLock tryLock(timeout,timeUnit) method , when
running below code it seems tryLock timeout until the previous thread end,could anyone explains this?

```
public class MyService2 {
public ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

public void waitMethod() {
    try {
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " enter ");
        boolean b = lock.tryLock(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        if (b) {
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + " lock begin:" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE / 10; i++) {
                Math.random();
            }
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + " lock end " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            return;
        }
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " got no lock end ");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (lock.isHeldByCurrentThread()) {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    MyService2 myService2 = new MyService2();
    Runnable runnable = myService2::waitMethod;
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(runnable);
    thread1.setName("T1");
    thread1.start();
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(10);
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(runnable);
    thread2.setName("T2");
    thread2.start();
}
```

after running this code ,the result is like that

```
1555343172612 T1 enter 
1555343172613 lock begin:T1
1555343172627 T2 enter 
1555343179665 lock end T1
1555343179665 T2 got no lock end
```

my question is why thread T2 doesn't timeout in 2s rather than waiting until thread T1 ends?

BUT I just found:

1. if replace Math.random() with TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1) for example ,it works fine.
2. if run in debug mode ,it works fine too.

Comment: This works fine for me. Check that your OS isn't occupied with other processes or that your JVM isn't blocked in GC or otherwise paused.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis thanks for your suggestion ,I'll give a try .

Comment: "Fairness" in scheduling when threads runs cannot be generally assumed.  When running with multiple threads, or with explicit thread management durations (explicit wait times) it's unsafe to assume that a thread will immediately resume at the conclusion of the explicit duration.

Comment: The issue is the unexpected long time in 'boolean b = lock.tryLock(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);'.  What may be happening is that the second tread is prevented from running for a long time while in the midst of the call to 'tryLock'.

Comment: @ThomasBitont  Sorry,I don't get it .what I learned from javadoc is only that "If the lock is held by another thread then the current thread becomes disabled for thread scheduling purposes and lies dormant until one of three things happens:
The lock is acquired by the current thread; or
Some other thread interrupts the current thread; or
The specified waiting time elapses";

Comment: That documentation is misleading, and perhaps incomplete.  "lies dormant until" seems to imply that the thread will immediately wake after the time elapses, but there is no guarantee of this.  There is also no guarantee that the dormant period will begin immediately.  As far as I'm aware, java does not guarantee timely execution of threads, as would a real time environment.  There can be arbitrary delays at any point of the invocation of 'tryLock' independent of the specified two seconds.

Comment: @ThomasBitonti but how to explain "runing under debug mode works fine" or "replace Math.random() with TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1) also works fine"

Comment: Both of those will considerably change the running characteristics of the program.  Running a debugger adds a whole new layer of control over when threads run.  Running 'Math.random' in a loop will tend to keep a thread as the running thread, whereas invoking sleep explicitly means the thread is not running, and explicitly gives other threads more opportunities to run.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an alternate which has a number modifications:

First, cleanups.  Clearer names.  Less intrusive logging.  Relative time values.

Second, the 0.1s sleep between the launch of the two compute threads is moved into each of the threads.  That more clearly gives precedence to the thread which launches the compute threads.

Third, the launch thread has joins with the compute threads.  That is to tie the conclusion of the computation to the launch thread.  In the original code, there is no management of the compute threads after they have been launched.  If the compute threads are intended to be unmanaged, that needs to be documented.

Fourth, the entire launch thread plus two compute threads structure is replicated.  That is to place give the structure a more realistic runtime environment, and, to present the different behaviors of the structure together in a single view.

A theme to the modifications is to provide clarity, both to the intended behavior of the program, and to the actual behavior (as viewed through the logging output).  The goal is to provide maximal clarity to these.

An additional modification is recommended, which is to put the log statements into a cache, then display the collected log lines after all of the computation cells have completed.  That removes behavior changes caused by the log statements, which are often considerable.

```
package my.tests;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class LockTest {

    private static long initialTime;

    protected static void setInitialTime() {
        initialTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public static long getInitialTime() {
        return initialTime;
    }

    public static final int CELL_COUNT = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        setInitialTime();

        System.out.println("Beginning [ " + Integer.toString(CELL_COUNT) + " ] computation cells");

        Thread[] cellThreads = new Thread[CELL_COUNT];
        for ( int cellNo = 0; cellNo < CELL_COUNT; cellNo++ ) {
            final String cellNoText = Integer.toString(cellNo);
            Runnable computeCell = () -> { 
                (new LockTest(cellNoText) ).compute();
            };
            Thread cellThread = new Thread(computeCell);
            cellThreads[cellNo] = cellThread;
        }

        // Start them all up ...

        for ( Thread cellThread : cellThreads ) {
            cellThread.start();
        }

        // Then wait for them all to finish ...

        for ( Thread cellThread : cellThreads ) {
            try {
                cellThread.join();
            } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
                System.out.println("Unexpected interruption: " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Completed [ " + Integer.toString(CELL_COUNT) + " ] computation cells");
    }

    //

    public LockTest(String cellName) {
        this.cellName = cellName;
    }

    private final String cellName;

    public String getCellName() {
        return cellName;
    }

    // Logging ...

    public String formatTime(long timeMs) {
        return String.format("%12d (ms)", new Long(timeMs));
    }

    public long getRelativeTime(long currentTime) {
        return currentTime - getInitialTime();
    }

    public String formatRelativeTime(long timeMs) {
        return String.format(
            "%12d %8d (ms)",
            new Long(timeMs),
            new Long( timeMs - getInitialTime() ));
    }

    public void log(String methodName, String message) {
        long timeMs = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();

        System.out.println(
            formatRelativeTime(timeMs) + ": " +
            methodName + ": " +
            threadName + ": " + message);
    }

    //

    public void compute() {
        log("compute", "ENTER: " + getCellName());

        Runnable computation = () -> {
            guardedComputation(
                100L, 0,                  // Pause 0.1s before attempting the computation
                1, TimeUnit.SECONDS,      // Try to obtain the computation lock for up to 1.0s.
                Integer.MAX_VALUE / 60 ); // Run this many computations; takes about 2s; adjust as needed
        };

        Thread computer1 = new Thread(computation);
        computer1.setName( getCellName() + "." + "T1");

        Thread computer2 = new Thread(computation);
        computer2.setName( getCellName() + "." + "T2");

        // Run two sets of computations:
        //
        // Each will pause for 0.1s before performing the computations.
        //
        // Performing computations requires a computation lock; wait up to 2.0s
        // to acquire the lock.

        computer1.start();
        computer2.start();

        try {
            computer1.join();
        } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
            System.out.println("Unexpected interruption: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        try {
            computer2.join();
        } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
            System.out.println("Unexpected interruption: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        log("compute", "RETURN: " + getCellName());
    }

    // Computation locking ...

    private final ReentrantLock computationLock = new ReentrantLock();

    public boolean acquireComputationLock(long maxWait, TimeUnit maxWaitUnit) throws InterruptedException {
        return computationLock.tryLock(maxWait, maxWaitUnit);
    }

    public void releaseComputationLock() {
        if ( computationLock.isHeldByCurrentThread() ) {
            computationLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    //

    public void guardedComputation(
        long pauseMs, int pauseNs,
        long maxWait, TimeUnit maxWaitUnit, int computations) {

        String methodName = "guardedComputation";

        log(methodName, "ENTER");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(pauseMs, pauseNs);
        } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
            System.out.println("Unexpected interruption: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        try {
            boolean didLock;
            try {
                didLock = acquireComputationLock(maxWait, maxWaitUnit);
            } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
                System.out.println("Unexpected interruption: " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }

            String computationsText = Integer.toString(computations);
            if ( didLock ) {
                log(methodName, "Starting computations: " + computationsText);
                for ( int computationNo = 0; computationNo < computations; computationNo++ ) {
                    Math.random();
                }
                log(methodName, "Completed computations: " + computationsText);
            } else {
                log(methodName, "Skipping computations: " + computationsText);
            }

        } finally {
            releaseComputationLock();
        }

        log(methodName, "RETURN");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is it they are trying? How is this piece of code different from theirs? How does the difference affect program execution and how does it explain the behavior the OP sees?